# Flutter BLoC Testing

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-bloc

I am using the flutter_bloc library and trying to do unit testing.
I am doing this pretty much as explained in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/unit-testing-with-bloc-b94de9655d86) and it's doing fine.

However, if a BlocState which extends Equatable (which required) has many properties or large list of items which extends Equatable, as well with their props[] defined as required.

This makes hard for the `expectLater()` to match proper emitted states because it tries to match the exact instance with its content and not only the state type or instance of.

For example:

Consider the following State class:

```
class BlocState extends Equatable{
     final List<String> data;
     BlocState({this.data});

     @override
     List<Object> get props => [data];
}
```

Then for emitted state like this:

```
List<String> data = ['Mark', 'Mike', 'John']
BlocState({data: data});
```

This expectLater will fail

```
 expectLater(
    bloc,
    emitsInOrder([BlocState(),]), //This will fail as the state does't equals exactly to the real state
  )
```

And this one will pass:

```
expectLater(
    bloc,
    emitsInOrder([BlocState(data: ['Mark', 'Mike', 'John']),]), //This will pass 
  )
```

On such simple state it's fine to verify exact content, but if the list will have 100 items how it can be tested?

Is there a way to verify just the instance type without the content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you could do something like this:

```dart
List<String> myData = ['Mark', 'Mike', 'John', 'AddAsManyAsYouLike'];
bloc.add(SomeEvent());

expectLater(
    bloc,
    emitsInOrder([BlocState(data: myData)])
)
```

Or if you only care about the right type you could use `isA<>()`

```dart
expectLater(
    bloc,
    emitsInOrder([isA<BlocState>()])
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Er1! The first part of your answer is good for simple content in did, but if it is List<ComplicatedObject> it will be messy to make a myData for it. 
And yes, isA<> is just what i was looking for! Thanks again @Er1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late but I had the same question and I found this:

```
List<String> myData = ['Mark', 'Mike', 'John', 'AddAsManyAsYouLike'];
bloc.add(SomeEvent());

expectLater(
    bloc,
    emitsInOrder([
        predicate<BlocState>(
            (state) => 
                state.oneOfMyProperties == 'expected value' &&
                state.anotherProperty == 'another expected value'
        )
    ])
)
```